# Замена значений датафрейм

Tags: python

Каким образом в датафрейме можно заменить нули первыми значениями до нуля, только в отношении к определенному столбцу?  `df['B'] =`

```
df =

A   B

1   7
2   0
3   0
4   9
5   0
6   2
```

Итог:

```
A   B

1   7
2   7
3   7
4   9
5   9
6   2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

можно так:

```
df["B"] = df["B"].replace(0, pd.NA).fillna(method="ffill")
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Когда в строках цифры заменяется хорошо, а вот когда такое : 2021-10-12T07:15 - почему то не заменяет нуль ниже. Что можно сделать?

Comment: @z4neo так вы пример датафрейма с такими данными приведите.